# C#, customise fileupload control

Tags: c#, file, file-upload

I'm creating a website that is able to do multiple file uploads. However, is it possible such that when I click on the browse button and select the file to upload, it automatically adds it to a list of files to be uploaded, instead of selecting the file, and having another button to add that selected file to the list? It is something like uploadify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Ajax Uploader](http://ajaxuploader.com/) for this

Answer (score 0):

Latest build of [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/AjaxControlToolkit) allows you to upload files without refreshing a page and without using addition button (not sure for multiuploading).

Also you may be interested in ["[How Do I:] Multiple File Uploads in ASP.NET 2"](http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-252.aspx).